# bin/ folder in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I noticed that there's a `bin/` folder in my module that holds the module folders and files. And it was added to `.gitignore` as a generated folder. Why would the android studio generate my source again?

[image: Screen of project tab of module]

What has made this and is this normal?

By the way my OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I checked `.idea/workspace.xml` and found `temporary="true"` in the `configuration` tag.

```
<configuration name="MyApp:app [build]" type="GradleRunConfiguration" factoryName="Gradle" temporary="true">
```

After deleting it, the sources are no longer duplicated in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` is a file telling **git** not to add the files into version control, this file is **not for** Android Studio.

Comment: I know what `.gitignore` is. I'm talking about a generated folder named `bin`. If the question is ambiguous please edit the way you think it's better.

Comment: You are asking how to disable auto-build in Android Studio?

Comment: No. I'm saying `gen` folder is a generated folder that holds all `.class` files. And there's a `bin` folder that holds the source itself. What exactly is the task of `bin`?

Comment: For a typical Android Studio project, there is no `bin` directory,

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Hello there. Sorry for interrupting, but have you find the answer?

Comment: Hey, I'm afraid not. Since then this issue never occurred on my new machines. So I let it go.